# Getting the ID of an added file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, post, mysqli

have the following table called filescontent

```
ID  |  version  |  fileContent  | ownerID
```

I need to get the ID of the file which is added by the user with a POST request and then I have to manipulte it.Could you help me out with this?

```
if($_POST) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, file_get_contents($_FILES ['uploadFile']['tmp_name']));

    $select_version = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT version FROM filescontent ORDER BY fileID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $fetch_version = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_version);
    $increment_version = $fetch_version['version'] + 1;
    echo '<br>'.$increment_version .' версия';

    $select_fileID = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT fileID FROM filescontent ORDER BY fileID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $fetch_fileID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_fileID);
    $increment_fileID = $fetch_fileID["fileID"] + 1;
    echo '<br>'. $increment_fileID.'ID';

    $selectName = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT fileName FROM files WHERE fileName='$name'");
    $fetchName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectName);
    $fetchName = $fetchName['fileName'];

    $selectIDname= "SELECT fileID FROM files WHERE fileName = '$name'";
    $selectIDnameQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $selectIDname);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectIDnameQuery);
    $selectIDname = $row['fileID'];
    echo '<br><pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>';

    $a = mysqli_error($connection);
    echo '<br>'.$a.'<br>';  

    if(!strcmp($name, $fetchName)){
        echo 'The file exists';
        $query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO filescontent (fileID, version, fileContent, author) VALUES ('$selectIDname', '$increment_version', '$data', 2)");
    }
    else{
        echo 'The file does not exist'; 
        $query2= mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO filescontent (fileID, version, fileContent, author) VALUES ('$increment_fileID', 1, '$data', 2)");
        $query3 = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO files (fileID, fileName, ownerID) VALUES ('$increment_fileID', '$name', 2)");
    }

    $a = mysqli_error($connection);
    echo '<br>'.$a.'<br>';  
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What is not happening right now?

Comment: Take a look of  `$mysqli->insert_id` 
`Returns the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT field that was updated by the previous query. Returns zero if there was no previous query on the connection or if the query did not update an AUTO_INCREMENT value.`

Comment: Everything is working here, but as I said I have to get the ID of the file which the user has uploaded.

Answer (score -1):

Use Below mentioned code , I have written it for you and let me know is it working for you or not :

```
if($_POST) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, file_get_contents($_FILES ['uploadFile']['tmp_name']));

$select_version = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT version FROM filescontent ORDER BY fileID DESC LIMIT 1");
$fetch_version = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_version);
$increment_version = (isset($fetch_version['version'])?$fetch_version['version']:0) + 1;
echo '<br>'.$increment_version .'<br>';

$select_fileID = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT MAX(fileID) as fileID FROM filescontent ");
$fetch_fileID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_fileID);
$increment_fileID = (isset($fetch_fileID["fileID"])?$fetch_fileID["fileID"]:0) + 1;
echo '<br>'. $increment_fileID.'ID';

$selectIDname= "SELECT fileID FROM files WHERE fileName = '$name'";
$selectIDnameQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $selectIDname);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectIDnameQuery);
$selectIDname = (isset($row['fileID']) ? $row['fileID']:null);
echo '<br><pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>';

$a = mysqli_error($connection);
echo '<br>'.$a.'<br>';  

if(!empty($selectIDname)){
    echo 'The file exists';
    $query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO filescontent (fileID, version, fileContent, author) VALUES ('$selectIDname', '$increment_version', '$data', 2)");
}
else{
    echo 'The file does not exist'; 
    $query2= mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO filescontent (fileID, version, fileContent, author) VALUES ('$increment_fileID', 1, '$data', 2)");
    $query3 = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO files (fileID, fileName, ownerID) VALUES ('$increment_fileID', '$name', 2)");
}

$a = mysqli_error($connection);
echo '<br>'.$a.'<br>';  
}
```

Comment: Why you are negating my ratings ?

Comment: You have given me (-)ve before checking the code. It is not fine dude you should have first test the code, I have written it for you

Comment: When I add a file it's ok, but when I add it for a second time is doesn't go in the DB and when i add it for a third time it goes to the DB...:/

Comment: Leave it even you don't know what is your question. Be prepare yourself first for asking questions then only give the answers